# Can't get xlink:href to work on 'a tag' in r2d3

Tags: internet-explorer-8, d3.js, raphael

I can add an 'a tag' to the rectangle element and I can add a link to plain text using r2d3 but for some reason I cannot get it to add a link to the 'a tag'.

I created a html file so that someone could download it and test it in ie8. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23726217/test.html

This is the specific code block that is creating the problem:

```
var kpi = svg.selectAll("rect")
           .data(data)
           .enter()
            .append("svg:a")
                .attr("xlink:href", (function (d) { return d.url }))
            .append("rect")
               .attr("width", 80)
               .attr("height", 30)
               .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.id) })
                .attr("rx", 5)
                .attr("ry", 5)
                .style("fill-opacity", 0)
               .attr("class", function (d) {
                   return (d.status);
               });
```

Comment: Does this problem only occur in IE8 or in other browsers as well?

Comment: Only in ie8, I am using d3 for all modern browsers and r2d3 for ie8. The link is working fine with d3, it is r2d3 that is creating the problem.